# Nested double quotes for wrapping variables

Tags: bash, shell

There is one line in my bash script file like this:

```
echo "$string" | sed -e "s|\($str\)|$(wrap \\1 $1 $2)|"
```

Now, I want to wrap the `$1` and `$2` with double quotes for preventing errors while `$1` equals to `null`.

I tried to add `\` before `"`, like `"\"$1\" \"$2\""` but it does not work.

How can I do that?

Comment: Using shell variables and command substitutions to _generate a `sed` script_ is terribly fragile.  Could you explain what `$string` and `$str` are and what you want to achieve. Are you generating commands that you later execute?

Comment: and as always, when writing "but it does not work", please show the exact command(s) you've entered, the result, any error messages you get, and what you expected to get instead.

Comment: Do you expect `wrap` to be invoked for every  line with the captured string as argument or do you expect `wrap` to be given a literal `\1` as argument and its output to be used to generate the content of the `sed` inline script?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer finally. I misunderstood the effect of double quotes. Actually, I only need to surround the characters that I need. So, I change the code like this:

```
echo "$string" | sed -e "s|\($str\)|"$(wrap \\1 "$1" "$2")"|g"
```

Comment: Yes. You are in a subshell inside the parentheses, so quotes in there are not affected by "outer" quotes.